# Why is my Ethereum balance still showing zero after transferring USDT into it?

Tags: python, web3py

I am making a website that allows users to have an Etherium wallet for everyone. So I used the web3 API to create wallets.

```
from web3 import Web3

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/b2862c602e244afa81a6b43d6d5a0a1a'))
web3.eth.account.create(#name)
```

result:

```
0xCcE984c41630878b91E20c416dA3F308855E87E2
```

I sent 500 USDT in order to check if this wallet is valid and receive USDT / ETH

```
web3.eth.get_balance('0xCcE984c41630878b91E20c416dA3F308855E87E2')
```

However, even though I've waited for 5 hours, it still tells me that the balance is zero.

Can etherium wallet not receive USDT coin? Or did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you created the ethereum address using web3.py on the main ethereum blockchain and not on tether's smart contract that resides inside of the ethereum blockchain.

You need to create the address inside the smart contract using the smart contract's method